# SelectAll Script not working on my site

Tags: javascript, html

So i have a bunch of these seperate by content in a form. But for some reason the single checkboxes become uncheckable and they all wont check when i click on toggle all.

Any idea?

```
<form>
    <input  type="checkbox" name="pkid[]" value="1">
    .... content blah blah ...
    <input  type="checkbox" name="pkid[]" value="2">
    .... content blah blah ...
    <input  type="checkbox" name="pkid[]" value="3">
    .... content blah blah ...
    <input  type="checkbox" name="pkid[]" value="4">  
    .... content blah blah ...



    <script language="JavaScript">
    function toggle(source) {
      checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('pkid[]');
      for each(var checkbox in checkboxes)
        checkbox.checked = source.checked;
    }
    </script>



    <input type="checkbox" onClick="toggle(this)" /> Toggle All<br/>
</form>
```

Is it possible its conflicting with these other javascript codes on my page?

```
     <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".vote-art, .home-art, .rss-art , .new-art").click(function(){

    if($(this).children("input").is(':checked'))
       {
       $(this).children("input").attr('checked',false);
       }
       else
       { 
       $(this).children("input").attr('checked',true);
       }

});
});
</script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){


    if($('#new-home').is(':checked'))
       {
       $('#new-hide').attr('checked',false);
       }
     if($('#new-hide').is(':checked'))
       { 
   $('#new-home').attr('checked',true);
   }


});
</script>
```

Comment: `for each .. in` might not be the best construct to use, especially if you're iterating and not enumerating. I would recommend a proper `for` loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your foreach loop to this

```
for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
}
```

Comment: @soniccool: do you have any js error? Check this sample http://jsfiddle.net/smuuF/

Comment: See its strange it works on jsfiddle and a simple html but in my actual code it doesnt work at all.

Comment: I edited my original post and posted other javascript codes i have maybe its conflicting?